# How to remove a live submit event in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two forms on our site #footer_leads and #footer_leads2 and i have a live submit event but need to verify a few things before the form gets summitted so i have this code

```
$('#footer_leads2, #footer_leads').live('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('again');                           
    var form = $(this);  //save reference to form
    if(somevalidation){
        form.die();
        form.submit(); //submit form
    }
```

I assumed the jQuery [die](http://api.jquery.com/die/) event would do the trick like in the above example but the page just into an infinite loop and crashes my browser....any ideas on how to do this

Comment: yes but the .die or unbind should remove this handler

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the jQuery `die()` page:

> Note: In order for .die() to function correctly, the selector used
>   with it must match exactly the selector initially used with .live().

Try `$('#footer_leads2, #footer_leads').die()` instead.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't need to remove the handler and resubmit. Just wait on the `preventDefault()` until you know whether or not the form passed validation:

```
$('#footer_leads2, #footer_leads').live('submit', function(e) {
  if (!somevalidation)
    e.preventDefault();

  // Else, the form will continue submitting unimpeded.
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you want to disable the form after the submit?

if yes, try this:
$('input[type=submit]', this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');

I hope its help,

Answer (score 1):

From the docs ( http://api.jquery.com/die/ ) :

> Note: In order for .die() to function correctly, the selector used
>   with it  must match exactly the selector initially used with .live().

You need to use `.unbind('submit')`

Answer (score 1):

Don't `unbind/die`.

Just submit the form with the native method.

```
$('#footer_leads2, #footer_leads').live('submit', function() {

    if (true /* validation succeeded */ ) {
        this.submit(); //submit form, but don't use jQuery's method
    } else {
        return false;
    }
});
```

---

**UPDATE:**

Since it sounds like you're making an AJAX call for the validation, you could just do the `this.submit()` in the `success:` callback.

```
$('#footer_leads2, #footer_leads').live('submit', function() {

    $.ajax({
        url: 'some/path',
        context: this,  // set the context of the callbacks to the element
        ...
        success: function( d ) {
            if( d.is_valid ) {
                this.submit();
            } else {
                // give some feedback to the user for validation failure
            }
        }
    });

    return false; // block the submit by default
});
```

Comment: I would have used this approach but i have an $.ajax call inside the live event that i need to make sure runs first before and i tried this approach but no go

Comment: @Tamer: In that case you would bind `this` to the context of the callback by including the context property like: `context:this`, then do `this.submit()` in the callback. I'll update just in case you're interested.

Comment: Might you be persuaded to get a pseudonimous username instead of @user113716? [Jon Skeet advises so.](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx)

Comment: Why not unbind/die... try duplicate submit is happen bug with setinterval, need just one submit. Work fine and look example: https://codepen.io/KingRider/pen/bReExj (JS Line: 15)